# iptables: Change destination-IP of TEE'd packets

Tags: iptables, iptables-redirect

Because of reasons I can't go into here, I found myself having to duplicate a UDP packet stream (netflow data, if it matters) to a second destination.

After some research, I discovered that the TEE target of `iptables`' mangle table did precisely that:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.81.21 --protocol udp --destination-port 6343 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.228.2 
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.81.21 --protocol udp --destination-port 6344 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.228.2
```

The only problem I have now is that the destination server at `192.168.228.2` receives the packets with a destination header of the original `192.168.81.21` address and therefore the software listening for the netflow traffic doesn't accept them.

The "obvious" solution would be to use `iptables`' own packet rewriting code to rewrite the destination header to the correct value, but that needs to *only* happen to the duplicated packets and not the originals. Which means my usual go-to of DNAT is out because that's only valid for the PREROUTING table, at which point I can't yet make a distinction between the normal and duplicated packets.

Unless there's something obvious I'm missing, I'm kind of stuck. Any suggestions?

Is there a way to add a rule for POSTROUTING that will change the IP-address of the packet to the correct destination server?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @kannaj Sadly, no. I eventually gave up and tried a different workaround for my specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the below iptable rule to the machine where the cloned packet is sent to:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 9003 -j NETMAP --to xx.xx.xxx.xx
```

What this does, is it changes the destination IP of any UDP packet destined to port `9003` to the private IP address.

Comment: That sounds like it might work. Unfortunately, I'm no longer in a position to test it because that setup has been torn down in favour of something else, but have a +1 anyway.